# Apache rewriterule for url encode query string only

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to use Apache rewrite engine to URL encode the query string only. Can any one give me a good solution. For example: the url is https://www.example.com/index.php?a=1&b=2&c=3. I only want to url encode the query string after the ?: a=1&b=2&c=3. I do not need to url encode any directory or page. Thanks.

A simply solution to solve this problem.

Comment: What is the underlying problem you are trying to resolve here? What you are asking does not quite make sense, since Apache rewrite engine / `.htaccess`" is likely _too late_ I would think? If the query string needs encoding as part of the incoming request(?) then it should already be URL-encoded before it reaches Apache/`.htaccess` (ie. your server). And which part exactly do you want to URL encode? The entire query string as `a%3D1%26b%3D2%26c%3D3`?! Or the individual params (although in your example, the params don't need encoding)?

Comment: I want url encode the entire query string only: a=1&b=2&c=3